# How to manage to put an int value from Jsonobject into query?

Tags: php, android, json

The app send a String/Jsonobject with POST method to a PHP file.
And I want to use that value to set the Limit in the query

```
$sql = "select * from posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $tag";
```

I can receive it but i can't use it into my query.
I got errors like "java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray"
I tried to convert it into Integer :

```
$int = intval($tag);
```

but the query still doesn't see it as an Integer..

There is another way to get an Int from Activity.java to php so that i can put it in the query after ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT ?

Java

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("tag", "2");
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject(params);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
```

Php

```
<?php

    //open connection to mysql db
        $connection = mysqli_connect("xxxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx")
 or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    if (empty($data['tag']) == false) {
       $tag = $data['tag'];
    }

            //fetch table rows from mysql db 
        $sql = "select * from posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $tag";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) 
or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: `$tag` not `&tag` .

Comment: Just a typo error here ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this

```
$sql = "select * from posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT '".$tag."';";
```

Comment: Thx for the reply, i get JSONExecption: Value Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.
I tried to $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $tag);
fclose($myfile);

Comment: and i get to the value in the file... for exemple 6 ..
do you think i need to convert it to another type ? like i said even intval works to convert but still the query dont see it as INT or even String

Comment: If you only need do send a int parameter, I suggest, avoid `JSONRequest` and simply use `GET` method approach like this
`<?php`
 `if(!empty($_GET)){`
  `$tag=$_GET['tag'];`
  `$connection = mysqli_connect("xxxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));`
  `$sql = "select * from posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT '".$tag."';";`
  `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));`
 `}`
`?>`
And send your value from android by `http://localhostOrSomethingYouAreUsing.php?tag=2`
Feel free to inform me your prob

Comment: That's how i resolved the problem ! Thank you Lushan !